# display:table-row not working

Tags: css, tablerow

I have a client form which includes HTML served up from an iframe - I can't edit it. The only thing I can do is apply CSS edits.

I'm trying to apply a simple adjustment which would stack the `<td>`s in the form so

```
1. What is your age?
```

becomes

```
1.
What is your age?
```

If you right click the first question and `Inspect Element` you'll see the rather interesting DOM structure I get to work with. This example it looks like this:

```
<div id="Age" class="questionlabel">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">   
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="questionnumber_questionlabel">1. </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label class="required">What is your age?</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

When I inspect that `<td>` and add a `display:table-row;` it completely ignores me. This is in Chrome - I can replicate this DOM and [get the CSS to do what I want in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/CSMAQ/) so I'm thinking there is a reset somewhere I can't see. I even tried `display:table-row !important;` to no avail. I can apply `border:2px solid blue;` no problem. I can apply `display:none;` no problem.

Any ideas as to what is going on here that would prevent this simple CSS param from working?

To re-iterate the ONLY thing I can do is apply CSS - No JavaScript and no HTML edits. Basically I pass in a CSS file in the url to the iFrame. That's all I get. Thanks!

*EDIT: I apologize I had to remove the link to the example form on the live site.*

Comment: I'm not seeing the `display: table-row;` declaration in Firebug's inspect of the styles associated with that element on the first link. Not even that it's being overridden.

Comment: Yea it's not in there yet - im adding it WITH firebug and it's not applying.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying; when I add a `style` attribute, it doesn't take effect, but if I add it to the `td` selected css block, it does work. That's very strange.

Comment: This works fine for me on that U.P. page in FF5/Firebug:  `table#form_table div.questionlabel td {display: table-row !important;}`

Comment: Would you mind posting a [screenshot](http://www.scrnshots.com) of your firebug + result? Even with that syntax I can't seem to get it to acknowledge the CSS. Tried both on FF5.0 and Chrome 12.0.742.122. Feel free to put it as an answer man. Thanks~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Edit - screenshots had to be removed, but the solution is still valid.*

Added this code to ***form-css.css***, using Firebug.  Beginning or end, it did not matter:

```
table#form_table div.questionlabel td {display: table-row !important;}
.questionnumber_questionlabel {margin: inherit!important;}
```

(Note: I reset that margin as the old one (-10px) was causing unsightly overlap.)

Comment: Thanks Brock! That helped a lot :)